# Linked list: Insert function points to itself after second insertion

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, insert

I was working on linked list, and I was to make an insert function. The list is created from a file containing student name and score and in sorted manner, the first try I inserts a new node it is ok, but the second try makes the new node to point to itself instead of pointing to null or at the node in which it was inserted before. I can't seem to find where the line that causes the node to point to itself while it does not happen in the first try!

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[20];  
    int score;    
    struct student *next;
} Student_Data_Type;

Student_Data_Type *insert(Student_Data_Type *head, Student_Data_Type *p)
{
    if(head == NULL)//if the head is empty then create list 
    {
        head = Readfromfile(head);
    }
    Student_Data_Type *bufferStack = head;
    Student_Data_Type *prev;
    prev = malloc(sizeof(Student_Data_Type));
    bool inserted = false;
    while(bufferStack->next != NULL && 
      strcmp(bufferStack->next->name, p->name) < 0)

    {
        bufferStack = bufferStack->next;
    }
    p->next = bufferStack->next;
    bufferStack->next = p;
    printf("[####] ADDED %s   %d\n",bufferStack->next->name, bufferStack->next->score);//Second try says pointing to the same node
    prev = bufferStack->next;
    printf("[##] AND IS POINTING TO %s %d\n", prev->next->name, prev->next->score);
    inserted = true;
    return head;
}
```

Here is the output in both the first and the second insert:-

```
//This is the initial list created from the file
[###] DISPLAYING NAMES AND SCORE OF STUDENTS:- 
[###] ChenZhiheng <-----> 67
[###] GaoSuxiang <-----> 89
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
[###] ZhangCheng <-----> 95
1.create list(read from file)
2.display all records
3.insert a record
4.delete a record
5.query
0.exit

//INSERT ONE
[###]ENTER NAME PLZ: Noor
[###] ENTER SCORE: 88
[####] ADDED Noor   88
[##] AND IS POINTING TO ZhangCheng 95
1.create list(read from file)
2.display all records
3.insert a record
.......

 //NOW DISPLAYING THE LIST AFTER INSERTING:-
[###] DISPLAYING NAMES AND SCORE OF STUDENTS:- 
[###] ChenZhiheng <-----> 67
[###] GaoSuxiang <-----> 89
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
[###] Noor <-----> 88
[###] ZhangCheng <-----> 95
1.create list(read from file)
 ......
//THEN THE SECOND INSERT TRY
[###]ENTER NAME PLZ: Layla
[###] ENTER SCORE: 90
[####] ADDED Layla   90
[##] AND IS POINTING TO MaQianli 90
1.create list(read from file)
......
//THEN I CALL MY DISLAY FUNCTION AGAIN AND THIS IS THE OUTPUT:
[###] DISPLAYING NAMES AND SCORE OF STUDENTS:- 
[###] ChenZhiheng <-----> 67
[###] GaoSuxiang <-----> 89
[###] Layla <-----> 90
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
[###] Layla <-----> 90
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
[###] Layla <-----> 90
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
[###] Layla <-----> 90
[###] MaQianli <-----> 90
 ....AND FOREVER LOOP,...

//HERE IS MY DISPLAY FUNCTION
void DisplayAll(Student_Data_Type *head)
{
 Student_Data_Type *stackbuffer = head;
 printf("[###] DISPLAYING NAMES AND SCORE OF STUDENTS:- \n");
 while(stackbuffer != NULL)
  {
   printf("[###] %s <-----> %d\n", stackbuffer->name, stackbuffer->score);
   stackbuffer = stackbuffer->next;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole `prev` is unused and using `malloc` for it wastes memory. In your `printf` statement you use `prev` which is actually your original `p` so `prev->next` is your original `bufferStack->next` which could be null or could be something else you don't intend.

As your code stands now, remove any use of `prev` and it should work. Your insertion code seems correct.

p.s.: also remove `inserted` as it is not used.

---

Silly Noor... The error is in a part you didn't show us, your case 3:

```
int main()
{
Student_Data_Type *head,*p;
    ...
    case 3:     
            ...
            strcpy(p->name, Student_Insert);  /// <-- copy where????
            p->score = Score_Insert;
            head = insert(head, p);
            break;
```

Now, where is the memory for `p` allocated??? You are lucky you didn't get a segmentation fault, as `p` is not initialized (it is initialized, but that is because you first did a query or so).

Comment: I have removed the prev and insert, still no change @paul-ogilvie

Comment: There must be something wrong in the rest of your code as he insert seems corect.

Comment: Here is the the full code in github...
https://github.com/farooqy/data_structure/tree/master

Comment: You are right, I forgot to allocate the space, and my compiler did not give me seg fault, but now it works fine, Thanks.